# Почему если обернуть file_get_contents в функцию, то PhpStorm не видит $http_response_header?

Tags: phpstorm

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://toster.ru/';

const WITH_WRAP = 1;
const WITHOUT_WRAP = 2;

$mode = WITHOUT_WRAP;

function some_func($url) {
  $result = file_get_contents($url);
  var_dump($http_response_header);
}

switch ($mode) {
  case WITH_WRAP:
    some_func($url);
    break;
  case WITHOUT_WRAP:
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    var_dump($http_response_header);
    break;
}
```

Если $mode равен WITH_WRAP. И если я поставлю точку останова на строке:
`var_dump($http_response_header);`
В функции some_func. То PhpStorm не видит переменную $http_response_header. Однако она существует - если продолжить выполнение программы, то это переменная выводится (вызов var_dump).

Если $mode равен WITHOUT_WRAP. И если я поставлю точку останова на строке:
`var_dump($http_response_header);`
В switch. То PhpStorm видит переменную $http_response_header.

Прикладываю скриншоты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Бывают некоторые глюки с оптимизацией

Comment: @KAGGDesign, а как исправлять их? Может, можно отключить оптимизацию как-нибудь? Я лучше пожертвую производительностью, чем точностью данных.

Comment: да они точные. Надо приспособиться.